# Writing custom HtmlHelper with razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

For my current work project we are using asp.net mvc 3.
As I have been out of the asp.net mvc game since after version 2 I'm a bit rusty, but have been following blog posts.
The views from the existing project tend to be a bit complicated and somewhat hard to read. I want to pull parts into separate components so that they are a bit easier to understand.

From reading articles in the past I seem to remember that pulling parts into components was made easier in the new razor syntax. If I remember correctly you could write custom HtmlHelpers by writing razor rather then coding it entirely with the tagbuilder.

The official asp.net tutorials are not helping me out and seem to mostly handle the old versions of asp.net mvc

Am I mixing a few things up?
What are terms I could use for googling?
What are good sources I could consult?

Answer (score 0):

.. And then I found the project is already using what I'm looking for.
It was the @helper syntax as explained here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx